# Is it possible to restrict unfreezing rows in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried following steps:

1) For a spreadsheet, Freeze first row

2) Apply protection on first row so that only I can edit it

3) Share spreadsheet with someone and give them edit permissions (They need to have edit permissions)

4) They cannot insert/change data but they are able to unfreeze rows

Is it possible to freeze header row so that one cannot unfreeze it even with edit permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You can go into the sheet and set the cells of your header as a "protected" range, in which you can set permissions for this particular range. In the screenshot below you can see how to do it manually, you select the range, right click, go to **protect range** and a side menu will appear, go to **Set permissions** and it will allow you to choose who gets edit permissions for that range.

[image]

Additionally, [here is some documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) on how to do the same programmatically, in case that aligns better with your intentions.